# Memory is delete always needed in Qt C++?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

I have used and modified the sample code below:

```
void MyScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) 
{ 
myPath = new QGraphicsPathItem();
previous = event->scenePos(); 
QPainterPath p; 
p.moveTo(previous); 
myPath->setPath(p); 
this->addItem(myPath);
}

void MyScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) 
{ 
if(myPath) 
{ 
QPainterPath path = myPath->path(); 
previous = event->scenePos(); 
path.lineTo(previous); 
myPath->setPath(path); 
} 
}
```

it is part of a simple 'sketch system'. What I find strange is that the pointer:

```
QGraphicsPathItem *myPath;
```

does not take a constructor or allow:

```
myPath = new QGraphicsPathItem(this); // this code will fail - why?
```

I would have thought that would aid the clean up / deletion of the pointer. Why does this not leak memory? Or does it? I have used Valgrind from within QTCreator and it doesn't seem to show any memory leak. Should I have in some location:

```
delete(myPath); // is this needed?
```

Can anybody explain or point to a concise explanation of when delete is needed please specifically within QT. I am looking at QPointer and QSharedPointer, probably a better approach.

I find Valgrind difficult to use on the command line with a QTCreator created application as it seems to get confused with the GUI objects being created etc and spits out hundreds and hundreds of lines. From within QTCreator I have tested valgrind with simple cases and it just points to the correct lines and nothing else - far far easier. Without the line above:

```
delete(myPath); // is this needed?
```

Valgrind doesn't seem to show a memory leak. Why?

How much can I trust Valgrind from within QtCreator?

Comment: As per documentation in http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#addItem, Scenes "Take Ownership" of the item you pass it. That means, it will be deleted by the scene when the scene is destroyed (scene's destructor). If you decide to delete it manually, I bet that would result in a double delete. Why that is shown as a memory leak i am not sure.....Someone else can take over on that point.

Comment: Just realized you didn't say it showed a memory leak with the double delete, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert on Qt but I assume `MyScene` inherits from [QGraphicsScene](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html). In which case, [addItem()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#addItem) takes ownership of `myPath` and will `delete` it when needed.

As long as you have passed ownership of the `QGraphicsPathItem` to some other object you don't have to delete it but up to that point you are responsible for the memory. Watch out for code paths where `addItem()` is not called because then you might need to call `delete`. For example, if an exception is thrown.

This kind of pattern is a little out dated but is still common in scene graph based graphics frameworks.